# Who was Koushika (of Koushika gotra)?

Tags: gotra

They say one shouldn't dig into rishi-moolam and nadi-moolam, cos it is very hard to find source.. but still curious.

When mentioning gotra during abhivaadaye, there is a rishi-pravara : Vaishvamitra, Aaghamarshana, Koushika - is the lineage for koushika gotra.

Was this Koushika the same as Vishvamitra before he became Brahma Rishi by tapas? Or was it another rishi called Koushika in the Vishvamitra lineage ? cos it is common to call someone by a distinguished ancestor's name (e.g. Raghava, or Kourava).
Was this Koushika a Brahma rishi or Raja rishi ? Are his descendants brahmanas or kshatriyas ?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kaushik

Comment: Just curious. Is it Vishvamitra or Vaishvamitra in the pravara?

Comment: @SreeCharan - Vaish

Answer (score 1):

There is a belief that Vishwamitra and Kaushika are same person but then why would there be two pravaras of Kaushika and Vishwamitra in same gotra?

The pravara of Kaushika gotra is " **Vaiswaamitra, Aghamarshana, Koushika "** and the pravara of Vishwamitra gotra is " **Vaiswaamitra, Devaraata, Owtala**"

Technically, Vishwamitra is also called "kaushika" because he was the descendant of Rishi Kusha.

> There was a king named [Kusha](http://www.valmikiramayan.net/bala/sarga51/bala_51_prose.htm), a brainchild of Prjaapati, and Kusha's
> son was the powerful and verily righteous Kushanaabha. One who is
> highly renowned by the name Gaadhi was the son of Kushanaabha, and
> Gaadhi's son is this great-saint of great resplendence, Vishvamitra.
> Vishvamitra ruled the earth, and this great-resplendent king ruled the
> kingdom for many thousands of years. At one time the great-resplendent
> king Vishvamitra went round the earth marshalling a unit of akshauhini
> army.

So King Gaadhi was the grandson of King Kusha and the father of Vishwamitra. Hence Vishwamitra is also known by the name "Kaushika" because his ancestor was Raja-rishi Kusha.

He was also a king but also a **rishi**. He is the rshi for the mantra of Rigveda. For example **he is the rishi of the mantra [3.31](https://doc-14-bc-docs.googleusercontent.com/docs/securesc/ha0ro937gcuc7l7deffksulhg5h7mbp1/79u3482fvg58f95l05le1tb7di9mbthr/1491667200000/02058467015715614041/*/0ByTrbPQHgxJdVlpubndDcm41OFk)**

Hence Kusha was the propagator of Kaushika gotra and then again Viswhamitra was the propagator of Vishwamitra gotra.